# xtrapivotgrid hitinfo get underline data sounce

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a xtrapivot data grid to show customer data. I am using a list of customer object as xtra pivot grid data source. Now i would like to get the underline customer object when right  click on any customer name row. Is that possible? please find the pivot grid pic in the attachment.

```
private void _pivotGridControl_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
    {

       //e.HitInfo.Field is null here.

    }
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.
Please let me know if the question is not clear enough.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PopupMenuShowingEventArgs.HitInfo.ValueInfo` property to obtain underline `Customer` object by using its `ValueInfo.Value` property.
Here is example:

```
private void pivotGridControl_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var valueInfo = e.HitInfo.ValueInfo;

    if (valueInfo == null || valueInfo.Field.FieldName != "Customer")
        return;

    object customer = valueInfo.Value;

    //...
}
```

Comment: valueInfo.Value only Gets the column field or row field value that corresponds to the currently not the underline data source.

Comment: @IamaC It's unclear what are you trying to get. Can you add to your question a sample class for your `Customer` object? What exactly you're trying to achieve?